# Partially preprocess a C or C++ source file?

Tags: c++, c, include, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to partially pre-process a **C** or C++ source file? By "partially preprocess" I mean expanding some but not all of the #include directives. For example, I would like to expand #includes pointing to my project headers, but not #includes pointing to other libraries' headers.

I tried to do this by running `gcc -E` with only the `-I` flags for my project headers and not the `-I` flags for the libraries, but that doesn't work because gcc gives an error when it encounters an #include it cannot expand.

**EDIT**: I do not really care about the preprocessor's behaviour with respect to macro expansion.

Comment: Would you want it to expand macros present in the un-included headers?

Comment: @Marcelo: I don't really care either way.

Answer (score 6):

The C preprocessor isn't smart enough to do this on its own. If you're only interested in `#include`, you should just roll your own tool (in, say, Perl) to process the source files, expanding `#include` lines that interest you and ignoring the rest.

This script prefixes uninteresting header lines with `// Ignored`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @uninteresting = qw(iostream vector map);
my $uninteresting = join '|', @uninteresting;

while (<>) {
    s%(#include <(?:$uninteresting)>)%// Ignored $1%;
    print;
}
```

Now you can do:

```
cat sourcefile.cpp | perl ignore-meh.pl | g++ -E
```

And if you want to get really fancy:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

while (<>) {
    s%// Ignored (#include <[^>]+>)%$1%;
    print;
}
```

Now you can do:

```
cat sourcefile.cpp | perl ignore-meh.pl | g++ -E | perl restore-meh.pl
```

Answer (score 3):

The `#include` which you don't want to expand, you can replace with something like `$$$include` (in short, which cannot be understood by pre-processor). Preferably first you copy original files into the temporary files and then run `gcc -E <filename>;`. Once you are done, again replace to the original source files.

The only concern here is that you have to go and edit your source files at least once. But that may not be a big deal as you can use the facility provided by your text editor.

Comment: The problem is it's not just my .cpp file that includes library headers, but a lot of the project headers included by the .cpp file do to, so I'd have to change a lot of files...

Comment: But that's the only way out ! Whatever headers give error while preprocessing, simply go and replace them or preferably **comment** them.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?:

```
#include <always_include.h>
#include <another_always_include.h>

#ifdef PART_2_INCLUDES
 #include <part2.h>
 #include <part2a.h>
#endif

#ifdef PART_3_INCLUDES
 #include <part3.h>
 #include <part3a.h>
#endif

...
```

Then, to compile everything, `gcc -DPART_2_INCLUDES  -DPART_2_INCLUDES ...`  Or, since it seems like usually everything should be included by default and not including some items is the special case, reverse the sense of the tests:

```
#include <always_include.h>
#include <another_always_include.h>

#ifndef PART_2_INCLUDES_OMITTED
 #include <part2.h>
 #include <part2a.h>
#endif
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `-nostdinc` for [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html) (or [cpp](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html)).

```
gcc ... -nostdinc ...
```

Comment: This covers standard includes, but not e.g. boost library includes which I also don't want to expand.

Comment: I have no idea about C++. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, a partial header expansion is meaningless. Consider the following example:

```
#include <limits.h>

#if UINT_MAX > 0xffffffff
# include "fasthash_64.h"
#elif UINT_MAX == 0xffffffff
# include "hash.h"
#else
# error "int too small for hash implementation."
#endif
```

Comment: I guess it should leave conditional sections alone then.

Comment: @HighCommander4: So you are happy for it to not expand some non-system #includes? Of course, if there is no such conditional logic in non-system source code, then this is a non-issue.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean. Well, it could expand the #includes in both branches without touching the conditional logic, right?