# Any options for C preprocessor to only expand special macros?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

For a source level analysis, I need to expand macros except those `#include`, is it possible?

For example, in the following snippet, I only hope `assert` to be expanded as `__assert_fail`, rather than including `assert.h` and expand `assert`.

```
#include <assert.h>

int main(void) {
  assert(0); // expand this
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Since the definition for assert is in assert.h how do you propose to expand assert without including assert.h?

Comment: @shf301: That's what he's asking.

Comment: I think he's saying he only wants what's from the includes if it's used in the application. Compilers and linkers do that already, right?

Comment: @self. I hope to do some transforms firstly for the source code, but I hope to expand some `special` macros and keep others.

Comment: Are you trying to inject custom definitions of macros that should be used instead of the included definitions for a set of chosen ones?

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey Exactly. I will still adapt the regular process of compiling and linking later after some transformations for the source code.

Comment: There is no way to do that as far as I know.  Maybe possible if you do it the other way around.

Comment: Write your own C preprocessor that just expands the bits you want to expand.  The standard one won't do what you want.

Comment: @Till I just don't need to expand "#include"s, but keep other macros expanded.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want, but you may be looking for [unifdef](http://dotat.at/prog/unifdef/).

Comment: @JoeZ Ok, seems that I have to do that.

Comment: @Zack Thanks for showing me the link, I think it's illuminating.

Comment: Ow - so what you want is partial expansion. That sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482321/partially-preprocess-a-c-or-c-source-file

Comment: @JoeZ "Write your own C preprocessor..." That's not easy to do.   Check my bio for tools that have a full controllable preprocessor; you can tell it which specific items to expand.

Comment: @IraBaxter:  That's true for a full preprocessor.  I guess it depends on what the goal is.  If it's just to do a controlled expansion of a few macros in a known way, it could be a simple perl script with a handful of regexps.  Otherwise, the tools in your profile may be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to write your own pre-preprocessor.  If you follow the simple rule (which most people do) of keeping your includes at the top, it shouldn't be too difficult.

- Read the source file in, line by line, and figure out where the last include directive is.
- Create a temporary file which is an exact duplicate, except with an extra marker line to identify where the include directives end, and where the rest of the code begins.
- Send that temporary file through the C preprocessor.
- Find the marker line in the preprocessed file, and create a new file replacing everything before it with the include directives that were in the original file.

In fact, this should all be fairly easy to do in a shell script with command line tools that come with your OS.

If you don't follow the "includes at the top rule", it will only be a little more difficult.  You can insert marker lines before and after each include directive (or each set of consecutive include directives), keeping track of which directives were between which markers.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using gcc you use `-E` as a switch to just run the preprocessor on the file. This will expand out the all macros that are found within the file, but leave the rest of the source untouched. Further, you can then unifdef any macros that get expanded within your source using `-U`. See [GCC preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917316/gcc-preprocessor).

So, in this:

```
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  assert(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Invoking:

```
g++ -E assert_test.cpp -o assert_test.ii
```

Returns assert_test.ii:

```
# 1 "assert_test.cpp"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 30 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/predefs.h" 1 3 4
# 31 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 2 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "assert_test.cpp"
# 1 "/usr/include/assert.h" 1 3 4
# 36 "/usr/include/assert.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/features.h" 1 3 4
# 371 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h" 1 3 4
# 385 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h" 1 3 4
# 386 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h" 2 3 4
# 372 "/usr/include/features.h" 2 3 4
# 395 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h" 1 3 4
# 10 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-64.h" 1 3 4
# 11 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h" 2 3 4
# 396 "/usr/include/features.h" 2 3 4
# 37 "/usr/include/assert.h" 2 3 4
# 67 "/usr/include/assert.h" 3 4
extern "C" {


extern void __assert_fail (const char *__assertion, const char *__file,
      unsigned int __line, const char *__function)
     throw () __attribute__ ((__noreturn__));


extern void __assert_perror_fail (int __errnum, const char *__file,
      unsigned int __line, const char *__function)
     throw () __attribute__ ((__noreturn__));




extern void __assert (const char *__assertion, const char *__file, int __line)
     throw () __attribute__ ((__noreturn__));


}
# 2 "assert_test.cpp" 2

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  ((0) ? static_cast<void> (0) : __assert_fail ("0", "assert_test.cpp", 5, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__));
  return 0;
}
```

So, at least on my system:

```
assert(0);
```

expands out to the following:

```
((0) ? static_cast<void> (0) : __assert_fail ("0", "assert_test.cpp", 5, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__));
```

where `__assert_fail` is an externally defined function (and usually contained with `libc`); So to answer your question you can than just use your favourite text replace (sed/awk/perl) utility and expand out `assert(xyz);` into `((xyz) ? static_cast<void> (xyz) : __assert_fail ("xyz", "<file_name>", 5, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__));`